# Why can't IntelliJ IDEA import local packages in Go project?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, go, package

I'm using Idea plugin for Go to work with my project.
The structure of my project is the following:

[image]

controller, entity, model, repository etc - are local packages (where one can use another).

Unfortunately, Idea can't import one local package from another:

[image]

[image]

With remote packages everything is just fine.

My project settings:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are talking about https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047?pr=mps&offset=30&max=15 I don't think it's finished. I am having all kind of problems with it. Some packages are just not recognized. I couldn't find any logic in that.

Comment: Why not just use the full path?

Comment: please accept the answer if it satisfies you..

Answer (score 27):

In my case enabling **Enable Go modules integration** helped.

[image]

Comment: You should not link a screenshot uploaded to another site. There's a Image icon for inserting images on the formatting toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, i was about to go crazy!

Comment: For newer versions of Goland, Go has been moved outside of Languages & Frameworks and moved to the top of the settings menu.

Comment: This helped me as well

Answer (score 12):

you need to follow the correct project structure - https://golang.org/doc/code.html

basically, an environment variable called GOPATH should be set to your workspace root, such as ~/dev/go

in `$GOPATH/src` all the source code lives, for example, when you get a remote package from github, like `go get github.com/someone/somepackage`, the source code will be downloaded to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/someone/somepackage` and the import path from within a .go file is `"github.com/someone/somepackage".

your own code should live under `$GOPATH/src` as well, let's say it's `$GOPATH/src/me/myproject`, then your import path for entity and model are `"me/myproject/entity"` and `"me/myproject/model"`

Comment: Is it really intended that remote code is under `go/src` and your own code is under `src`? Just want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

For any one facing this issue, just tick the "Index entire GOPATH" option in Preferences->Go->GOPATH

Comment: Note that this only seems to work on a machine where you have direct access to all of the repos

Answer (score 1):

Once I updated Preferences -> Go -> GOPATH -> Module GOPATH to include the root directory of my project (i.e. the directory containing src, bin and pkg) the imports of sibling packages started working ok. The "Index entire GOPATH" option was on, but didn't seem to help.

Comment: It helps me on using old (1.7) go version with recent Goland.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the `Preferences -> Go -> GOPATH` worked for me.

[image: Indexing the <code>Preferences -> Go -> GOPATH</code> worked for me.]

Answer (score -2):

Please use one of the latest releases from [github releases page](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/releases) and these kind of issues should be fixed.

Thank you.